# Prefix to domain

Tags: web, dns

If I have a domain, such as `example.com`, how would I go about pointing `special.example.com` to a different website, say `www.google.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Domain Name Service providers web console (the place where you are managing domain records for `mydomain.com`), and add `CNAME` record:

```
special    CNAME    www.google.com
```

Keep in mind that this will only point `special.mydomain.com` to **ip address** of `www.google.com` which does not guarantee that the web server there will respond to requests for `Host: special.mydomain.com` (though some probably will).

(btw, the domain to use in questions/examples/documentation is not `mydomain.com` but usually `example.com`, as specified by [RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606))

Comment: great thanks, that worked! and I edited my question to use `example.com` instead.